# Issue with synchronizing threads in java

Tags: java, synchronization, synchronized

I'm trying to write an example program which consists of a bank account object that the amount of money can be modified in, and 10 slave objects that move 1 unit of currency a million times each from 2 different bank account objects. My intended outcome is for the sum of the bank account currencies to be 0 at the end, like what I start with. I've tried synchronizing the "setBalance" method in BankAccount, as I believe that's the one that should be synchronized, however that doesn't work. When I tried it on getBalance or run even those don't work either, so I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong.

BankAccount.java

```
public class BankAccount{

    private int balance;

    public BankAccount()
    {
        balance = 0;
    }

    public int getBalance()
    {
        return balance;
    }

    public void setBalance(int balance)
    {
        this.balance = balance;
    }
}
```

Slave.java

```
public class Slave extends Thread {

    BankAccount source;
    BankAccount target;

    int currency = 1;

    public Slave (BankAccount source, BankAccount target) {
        this.source = source;
        this.target = target;

    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            target.setBalance(target.getBalance() + currency);
            source.setBalance(source.getBalance() - currency);
        }
    }
}
```

Master.java

```
public class Master {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BankAccount account1 = new BankAccount();
        BankAccount account2 = new BankAccount();

        Slave[] slaves = new Slave[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (i < 5)
            {
                slaves[i] = new Slave(account1, account2);
            }
            else
            {
                slaves[i] = new Slave(account2, account1);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            slaves[i].start();
        }

        try
        {
            for (Slave s : slaves)
                s.join();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Interruption before completion of the joins" + e);
        }


        System.out.println("Sum of balances: " + (account1.getBalance() + account2.getBalance()));
    }
}
```

Comment: The first thing you're missing is an example in this question of how you're using `synchronized`.

Comment: @JoeC true, forgot to include this

Comment: So, between the time it takes to `getBalance`, apply the operation (`+`/`-`) and `setBalance`, the actual balance might have changed.  It would be better to have a `withdraw` and `deposit` method which was synchronised. These methods would apply the operation (`+`/`-`)  to the `balance` themselves, in a single, protected, step

Comment: @MadProgrammer you are correct, however this is just an example program for myself to better understand how "synchronize" works. I want to do it using this code, regardless of how unpractical it is, which I believe should work with a "synchronize" in some method.

Comment: @user3487554 Off the top of my head, you would to need to synchronise around both the `target` AND `source` `BankAccount` instances in the `run` method to ensure that neither can be updated. This becomes dangerous as you could enter a deadlock scenario

Comment: Please edit your title to be more specific to your Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code ...

> ```
>             target.setBalance(target.getBalance() + currency);
> ```

... has its intended effect in a thread T1 only if `target`'s balance is not modified by a different thread between T1's invocation of `getBalance()` and its invocation of `setBalance()`.  Synchronizing one or both of those methods does nothing to prevent such an intervening modification, and your multiple threads are performing so many of those, so fast, that it's reasonably likely that you'll hit that issue.

The appropriate critical region thus encompasses *both* method invocations, which you can implement by putting them inside a `synchronized` block:

```
            synchronized(target) {
                target.setBalance(target.getBalance() + currency);
            }
```

Of course, you need to treat the update of `source` similarly.  Note well that for each critical region, all contending threads need to synchronize on the same object for the synchronization to have the desired effect.

Comment: Very well explained, exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `synchronized` keyword, if used in a method signature, takes a lock on the object being invoked.  If you wish to lock on an alternative object, you need to use the keyword in this way:

```
synchronized(objectToLock) {
    doAtomicStuff();
}
```

In your case, your atomic operation is getting, adjusting and setting the balance, and you will want to lock on the relevant `BankAccount` objects.

That should be enough for you to work out where and how to use `synchronized`.